# Java/LWJGL -- Issue with Player entity "sticking" to collision entities

Tags: java, lwjgl, game-engine, collision

This is my first time asking on Stack Overflow so bear with me haha.

I have been working on my first actual game with Java/LWJGL. I've had much success until dealing with collisions. I am not using the "normal" rectangle intersection methods but my own, tailored to (hopefully) be more flexible. If you would like me to post how all that works I would be glad to. The collisions work very well however my problem comes when trying to stop the player from entering the entity. My velocities are often more than 1.0 and can leave the player within the entity before I have a chance to set the velocity to zero. Once the player is inside the entity I can no longer move my player. Any ideas? Much thanks.

Posted below is the majority of the useful code:

**Entity Class :**

```
public class EntityPhysics extends Entity{

private float velX, velY;

private float gravity = 2f;

public EntityPhysics(float x, float y, int width, int height, Shader shader, Level level, Texture texture) {
    super(x, y, width, height, shader, level, texture);
    velX = 0;
    velY = 0;
}

@Override
public void update(){
    super.update();
    move();
}

public void move(){

    Console.println("PRE - " + velX + " " + velY);

    if(canMoveDown() && getY() > 0){    // Update velY with gravity
        velY -= gravity * (Properties.scale / 32f);
    }

    if(velX != 0 && velX > 0){          // Slow -velX
        if(canMoveLeft()){              
            velX -= 0.5f * (Properties.scale / 32f);
        }
    }

    if(velX != 0 && velX < 0){          // Slow +velX
        if(canMoveRight()){ 
            velX += 0.5f * (Properties.scale / 32f);
        }
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------//

    if(velY < 0 && !canMoveDown()){     // Check Collision Down
        velY = 0;
    }

    if(velY > 0 && !canMoveUp()){       // Check Collision Up
        velY = 0;
    }

    if(velX > 0 && !canMoveRight()) {   // Check Collision Right
        velX = 0;
    }

    if(velX < 0 && !canMoveLeft()) {    // Check Collision Left
        velX = 0;
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------//

    if(getY() < 0){     // Keep Y above 0
        setY(0);
        velY = 0;
    }

    if(getX() < 0){     // Keep X above 0
        setX(0);
        velX = 0;
    }

    if(getY() > getLevel().getHeight()){    // Keep Y below level height
        setY(getLevel().getHeight() - getHeight());
        velY = 0;
    }

    if(getX() > getLevel().getWidth()){     // Keep X below level width
        setX(getLevel().getWidth() - getWidth());
        velX = 0;
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------//

    Console.println("POST - " + velX + " " + velY);

    setX(getX() + velX / (Properties.scale * 2f));
    setY(getY() + velY / (Properties.scale * 2f));
}


public void jump(float speed){
    velY = speed * (Properties.scale / 32f);
}

public void moveUp(float speed){
    velY = speed * (Properties.scale / 32f);
}

public void moveDown(float speed){
    velY = -speed * (Properties.scale / 32f);
}

public void moveLeft(float speed){
    velX = -speed * (Properties.scale / 32f);   
}

public void moveRight(float speed){
    velX = speed * (Properties.scale / 32f);
}

public boolean canMoveUp() {
    if(CollisionHandler.getCollidedEntity(this) != null){
        Entity entity = CollisionHandler.getCollidedEntity(this);
        if(ExtraMath.intersectRange(entity.getY(), entity.getY() + entity.getHeight(), getY(), getY() + getHeight())){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

public boolean canMoveDown() {
    if(CollisionHandler.getCollidedEntity(this) != null){
        Entity entity = CollisionHandler.getCollidedEntity(this);
        if(ExtraMath.intersectRange(entity.getY(), entity.getY() + entity.getHeight(), getY(), getY() + getHeight())){
            return false;
        }           
    }

    return true;
}

public boolean canMoveLeft() {
    if(CollisionHandler.getCollidedEntity(this) != null){
        Entity entity = CollisionHandler.getCollidedEntity(this);       
        if(ExtraMath.intersectRange(entity.getX(), entity.getX() + entity.getWidth(), getX(), getX() + getWidth())){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

public boolean canMoveRight() {
    if(CollisionHandler.getCollidedEntity(this) != null){
        Entity entity = CollisionHandler.getCollidedEntity(this);
        if(ExtraMath.intersectRange(entity.getX(), entity.getX() + entity.getWidth(), getX(), getX() + getWidth())){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
} 
}
```

**Movement:**

```
    float speed = 6f;
    float jumpSpeed = 32f;

    if(InputHandler.isKeyPressed(GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE)){
        Console.println("GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE");
        super.stop();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    if(InputHandler.isKeyPressed(GLFW_KEY_SPACE)){
        player.jump(jumpSpeed);
    }

    if(InputHandler.isKeyHeld(GLFW_KEY_A)){
        player.moveLeft(speed);
    }

    if(InputHandler.isKeyHeld(GLFW_KEY_S)){
        player.moveDown(speed);
    }

    if(InputHandler.isKeyHeld(GLFW_KEY_D)){
        player.moveRight(speed);
    }

    if (InputHandler.isKeyHeld(GLFW_KEY_F1)) {
        GL11.glPolygonMode(GL11.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL11.GL_LINE);
    }

    if (InputHandler.isKeyHeld(GLFW_KEY_F2)) {
        GL11.glPolygonMode(GL11.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL11.GL_FILL);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I have since changed my collision method to using multiple boxes for detecting which side has collided. This method works fairly well however if I have a high velocity (gravity), the player will stick too far into the entity and collide with multiple sides. This method also has issues with multiple collisions.

```
public class EntityPhysics extends Entity{

private float velX, velY;

private float gravity = -2f;

private BoundingBox northBoundingBox, southBoundingBox, eastBoundingBox, westBoundingBox;

private boolean colliding;

private ArrayList<Collision> collisions = new ArrayList<Collision>();

public EntityPhysics(float x, float y, int width, int height, Shader shader, Level level, Texture texture) {
    super(x, y, width, height, shader, level, texture);

    northBoundingBox = new BoundingBox(this, 
            + 0.1f,
            getHeight() - 0.1f,
            getWidth() - 0.2f,
            0.2f);

    southBoundingBox = new BoundingBox(this, 
            + 0.1f,
            -0.1f, 
            getWidth() - 0.2f, 
            0.2f);

    eastBoundingBox = new BoundingBox(this, 
            getWidth() - 0.1f, 
            0.1f, 
            0.2f, 
            getHeight() - 0.2f);

    westBoundingBox = new BoundingBox(this, 
            -0.1f, 
            0.1f, 
            0.2f, 
            getHeight() - 0.2f);

    velX = 0;
    velY = 0;
}

@Override
public void update(){
    super.update();

    if(northBoundingBox != null){
        northBoundingBox.update();
        southBoundingBox.update();
        eastBoundingBox.update();
        westBoundingBox.update();
    }

    Console.println(northBoundingBox.getX() + ", " + northBoundingBox.getY() + ", " + northBoundingBox.getHeight() + ", " + northBoundingBox.getWidth());
    Console.println(southBoundingBox.getX() + ", " + southBoundingBox.getY() + ", " + southBoundingBox.getHeight() + ", " + southBoundingBox.getWidth());
    Console.println(eastBoundingBox.getX() + ", " + eastBoundingBox.getY() + ", " + eastBoundingBox.getHeight() + ", " + eastBoundingBox.getWidth());
    Console.println(westBoundingBox.getX() + ", " + westBoundingBox.getY() + ", " + westBoundingBox.getHeight() + ", " + westBoundingBox.getWidth());


    Entity entity = null;

    for(Entity e : EntityHandler.getEntities()){

        if(e != this && e.canCollide()){

            if(ExtraMath.rectangleIntersect(northBoundingBox, e.getBoundBox())){    
                Console.println("COLLIDING NORTH WITH: " + e);
                collisions.add(new Collision(e, Collision.NORTH));
                colliding = true;
                entity = e;
            }

            if(ExtraMath.rectangleIntersect(southBoundingBox, e.getBoundBox())){
                Console.println("COLLIDING SOUTH WITH: " + e);
                collisions.add(new Collision(e, Collision.SOUTH));
                colliding = true;
                entity = e;
            }

            if(ExtraMath.rectangleIntersect(eastBoundingBox, e.getBoundBox())){
                Console.println("COLLIDING EAST WITH: " + e);
                collisions.add(new Collision(e, Collision.EAST));
                colliding = true;
                entity = e;
            }

            if(ExtraMath.rectangleIntersect(westBoundingBox, e.getBoundBox())){
                Console.println("COLLIDING WEST WITH: " + e);
                collisions.add(new Collision(e, Collision.WEST));
                colliding = true;
                entity = e;
            }

        }
    }

    if(y > 0) 
        velY += gravity * (Properties.scale / 32f);

    if(y < 0){
        y = 0;
        velY = 0;
    }

    if(x < 0){
        x = 0;
        velX = 0;
    }

    if(velX != 0 && velX > 0){          
        velX -= 0.5f * (Properties.scale / 32f);
    }

    if(velX != 0 && velX < 0){          
        velX += 0.5f * (Properties.scale / 32f);
    }


    if(colliding){

        for(Collision collision : collisions){

            if(collision.getCollision() == Collision.NORTH && velY >= 0){
                setY(entity.getY() - entity.getHeight());
                velY = 0;
            }

            if(collision.getCollision() == Collision.SOUTH && velY <= 0){
                setY(entity.getY() + entity.getHeight());
                velY = 0;
            }

            if(collision.getCollision() == Collision.EAST && velX >= 0){
                setX(entity.getX() - entity.getWidth());
                velX = 0;
            }

            if(collision.getCollision() == Collision.WEST && velX <= 0){;
                setX(entity.getX() + entity.getWidth());
                velX = 0;
            }
        }   
    }

    colliding = false;
    collisions.clear();

    x += velX / (Properties.scale * 2f);
    y += velY / (Properties.scale * 2f);

}

public void jump(float speed){
    velY += speed * (Properties.scale / 32f);
}

public void moveUp(float speed){
    velY += speed * (Properties.scale / 32f);
}

public void moveDown(float speed){
    velY = -speed * (Properties.scale / 32f);
}

public void moveLeft(float speed){
    velX = -speed * (Properties.scale / 32f);   
}

public void moveRight(float speed){
    velX = speed * (Properties.scale / 32f);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Once your player goes in areas which should be unreachable, move it out  programmatically by changing its position directly, if you do it corretly, it wont be noticable.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I have done that and it works however I get shaking. The player is pushed in and out repeatedly.

Comment: I'd like to see methods that are responsible for your collision, maybe there is something wrong. Tag me like @Nebulous39 so ill get notification.

Comment: @eldo I have since rewritten most of my code. I will add an edit with the new code.